# codeigniter auto-loading or not

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I **disabled** auto-loading db just because many pages of my site don't need db connections or processing. If I need db processing, I manually do `$this->load->database();` when my page needs db support.

Now, What I want to know is this:
I will **enable** auto-loading and set `$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;` in configuration file. Is this going to work as same as the way above? I mean, will db be loaded when only db is needed in relevant pages (not in every single page calls), which is what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer is `NO`.

If you enable the `auto-loading` then it'll be automatically loaded in your controllers but if you set `autoinit=false` then it won't connect to the database when the library loads because by default the `db library` connects to the database when it loads.

> autoinit - Whether or not to automatically connect to the database
>   when the library loads. If set to false, the connection will take
>   place prior to executing the first query.

When `autoinit=false` the connection will be made just before the first `query` happens but it'll be loaded automatically and will be available in every controllers.

[**Read Here**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

Comment: So, in term of performance, I should disable **auto-loading** and continue using manual connection `$this->load->database();` since I don't need db support. Am I right?

Comment: Thank Heera, I asked one more [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710039/codeigniter-this-db-reconnect-usage) which might be in your area as well. Could you please have a look at it as well? Thanks again