# Codeigniter $this->db->reconnect(); usage

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I’m **not** autoloading db because most pages of my application **don’t** need db processing otherwise whole thing will slow down. What I want to do is not to establish a new connection to db when there is one already alive and use it instead not to bother server-db. So how do I implement `$this->db->reconnect();` to my example below? I read user guide but no exact example there.

**Note :** If I necessary to use `$this->db->close();` and `$this->db->initialize();` then please help me implement them as well because I heard that calling `$this->db->reconnect();` with autoloading disabled will throw an error.

I’m using CI 2.1

Thanks

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();

  $this->load->database();
 }

 public function function_a($id)
 {
  $this->db->protect_identifiers('year');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM year WHERE id = ?";

  $data['dbquery'] = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));

  return $data['dbquery'];
 }

 public function function_b($id)
 {
  $this->db->protect_identifiers('month');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM month WHERE id = ?";

  $data['dbquery'] = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));

  return $data['dbquery'];
 }


 public function function_c($id)...
 public function function_d($id)...
 public function function_e($id)...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically if you keep `pconnect=false` in `database.php` then the connection will be closed at the end of each script’s execution automatically and by default it set to `false`.

Well if you want then you can use

```
$this->db->close();
```

after every query execution to close the connection manually and use

```
$this->db->initialize();
```

before any query execution to initialize the connection again after closing it.

Comment: As I connect to db in constructor with `$this->load->database();`, what is the point of using `$this->db->initialize();`? I mean, what does it do special? Advantages and disadvantages? I cannot find any info about it on the web.

Comment: If you use `autoinit=false` and `pconnect=false` and when using `$this->db->close();`.

Comment: Understood, so no point of using close() and initialize() since `pconnect` is set to **false** by default in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is just close the connection and reconnect manually with:

```
$this->db->close();
$this->db->initialize();
```

Comment: Whereabouts do I put those 4 lines in my example above?